# How to close expanded tagfield when its label is clicked in ExtJS6?

Tags: extjs, extjs6

By default a `tagfield` cannot be closed when clicking on its field label, so if there is a form full of tag fields it's hard to find a sweet spot where you can click without expanding one of them.

I'd like to keep the `triggerOnClick` behavior when it expands whenever you click on the field itself. Is there a way to just make its label collapse the expanded field (something better than wrapping label-less field into a  container with a label).

```
{
    xtype: 'tagfield'
    fieldLabel: 'Tags',
    queryMode: 'local',
    triggerAction: 'all',
    forceSelection: true,
    editable: true,
    anyMatch: true,
    valueField: 'id',
    displayField: 'name',
    triggerOnClick: true,
    store: store,
}
```

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/17or

Comment: You could remove the "for" attribute from the label, it just uses the normal browser behaviour to cause focus.

Comment: Ok thanks, I redefined `Ext.form.field.Tag.prototype.labelableRenderTpl` and removed `for` from a label tag, it works but I feel i did something dirty, also it has a side effect of not opening a dropbox if it's closed. If anyone has any other suggestions please post them.

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution to edit the for-attribute. You can edit the value with

```
inputId: "myTagfieldIsNotSelectWhenIpressOnTheLabel"
```

This is a workaround when customers press on a label of a Extjs Tagfield and the field should close. Works in Chrome and Firefox.